# The annulus is connected without using path-connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

How to prove that this set $$\{z\in \mathbb{C}, 1<|z|<2\}$$ is connected ?

Thank you.

Comment: How about using the path-connectedness?

Comment: In the cours there is  the connectedness befor path-connectedness

Comment: So i want a proof without using path-connetedness that's why i asked this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to prove it is to note that it is the continuous image of a connected set and is therefore connected. For example, consider the continuous function $f : (1, 2)\times[0, 2\pi) \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ given by $(r, \theta) \mapsto re^{i\theta}$. The image of $f$ is precisely the annulus $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 1 < |z| < 2\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ denote the annulus given and let $r_1 e^{i\theta_1}$ and $r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$ each be in the annulus.  Consider the path $f_1:[0,1] \to A$ given by

$$
f_1(t) = r_1 \exp\left [i\theta_1 + it(\theta_2-\theta_1) \right ]
$$

and then the path $f_2: [0,1] \to A$ given by

$$
f_2(t) \;\; =\;\; (r_1 + t(r_2 - r_1)) e^{i\theta_2}.
$$

Glue these paths together to obtain $f_1 *f_2: [0,1] \to A$ taking $r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ to $r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the topology in play is the usual metric topology in the complex plane, the easy way to show the space is connected (in this case) is to show it is path connected, which is a stronger property and implies connectedness.

Tho show the space $S$ is path connected, consider any two disjoint points $a,b$. Since neither $a$ nor $b$ is the origin, we can write $a = r_a \cos \theta_a + i r_a \sin \theta_a$ and $b = r_b \cos \theta_b + i r_b \sin \theta_b$ (with, as it happens, 
$1 < r_a < 2$ and $1 < r_b < 2$).

Now consider the path along constant $\theta$ taking us from $a$ to $a'= \cos \theta_a + i r_b \sin \theta_a$ and then along constant $r_b$ (with changing $\theta$)  taking $a'$ to $b$.  This demonstrates that $a$ and $b$ are path connected, and since $a$ and $v$ were two arbitrary points in $S$, that $S$ is path connected.